# Swift array bounds error. Carefully constrained index - out of bounds anyway. Why?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Friends

I have some code very similar to the block below.

The line: `let item = selectedErrorList[i]` is blowing up because of a out of bounds error.

The context is a dialogue with two tabs: One displaying a `ScrollView` with ~100 elements, the other a `ScrollView` with about 4 elements.  When the user scrolls to the bottom of the big list and then clicks on the tab of the small list which will rerun this code, the error occurs

I am convinced that `i` is constrained to the indexes of `selectedList` and when the tab is changed everything should be reinitialised.  That would make this a bug in Swift.

Does this ring any bells for anyone?  Seen a similar problem?

```
    var selectedErrorList = array of items;
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: true){
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<selectedErrorList.count){ i in
                let item = selectedErrorList[i]
                // Do something with item
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not ForEach on selectedErrorList itself?

Comment: Because we use `i` in display: "Element N of M" style

Comment: Worik, if you could please add the code for the other ScrollView as well it'd be better. Otherwise it'll be very hard to reproduce and we won't be able to help much

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be : ForEach(0..<(selectedErrorList.count - 1)) ?

array index starts a zero , ends at number of indexes minus one.

Comment: But that is what `..<` takes care of.

Comment: you're right havent noticed the little < .

Answer (score 0):

Solved this.

Needed this to maintain the index:

```
private func adjustIndex(i: inout Int) -> Int {
//    This function is needed to increment the index `i`.  Because SwiftUI will not let code into a declaration but will let a function call, and `i++` is not a thing, let alone a function call, in Swift.
    let ret = i
    i += 1
    return ret
}
```

```
var i = 1
var selectedErrorList = array of items;
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: true){
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<selectedErrorList.count){ i in
                let item = selectedErrorList[i]
                // Do something with item
                someThingWithItem(item, adjustIndex(i: &i))
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the idiom that I was resulted in a warning from Swift (I had not noticed due to clutter in the console)

The `adjustIndex` function is a tacky hack but gets around the fact that   statements in a SwiftUI view are tricky.  I am new to SwiftUI and I have not figgured those rules yet, but:

```
            ForEach(0..<selectedErrorList.count){ i in
                let item = selectedErrorList[i]
                i += 1 // Error here
                someThingWithItem(item, i)
            }
```

will not work.

As a interesting aside:

```
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: true){
        LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
```

resulted in elements being added into the output `ScrollView` out of order when scrolling and switching between tabs.

I did think that SwiftUI did all =the GUI work in one thread.  I misunderstand, but that is another issue.